# How to exclude file types from Directory Iterator loop

Tags: php, file, iterator, directory, spl

Simple directory iterator that is recursive and shows all files and directories/sub-directories.

I don't see any built in function to exclude certain file types, for instance in the following example I do not want to output any image related files such as `.jpg`, `.png`, etc. I know there are several methods of doing this , looking for advice on which would be best.

```
$scan_it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/example_dir");

 foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($scan_it) as $file) {

  echo $file;
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:**
Ok, so I'm an idiot. PHP has a builtin for this: `pathinfo()`

Try this:

```
$filetypes = array("jpg", "png");
$filetype = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!in_array(strtolower($filetype), $filetypes)) {
  echo $file;
}
```

---

**Original Answer:**

Why not just run `substr()` on the filename and see if it matches the extension of the file type you want to exclude:

```
$scan_it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/example_dir");

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($scan_it) as $file) {
  if (strtolower(substr($file, -4)) != ".jpg" && 
      strtolower(substr($file, -4)) != ".jpg") {
    echo $file;
  }
}
```

You could make it easier by using regular expressions:

```
if (!preg_match("/\.(jpg|png)*$/i", $file, $matches)) {
   echo $file;
}
```

You could even use an array to keep track of your file types:

```
$filetypes = array("jpg", "png");
if (!preg_match("/\.(" . implode("|", $filetypes) . ")*$/i", $file, $matches)) {
   echo $file;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was doing , there are a lot of files so was wondering if it was the best method, thanks.

Comment: @Wyck: I just updated my answer since I realized there was a better way. Check out the `pathinfo()` example in my update.

Comment: If you're lucky enough to be playing with PHP 5.3.6 or above, there's also the [`getExtension()`](http://php.net/splfileinfo.getextension) method available on the `$file` itself.

Comment: I'm glad you kept the original answer. I needed the regex for a completely different situation and this answer helped a great deal!

Comment: Coming late to this party, why not use `in_array($fileSPLObject->getExtension(), <array of extensions>` in keeping with the SPLObject?

Answer (score 6):

From PHP 5.4 can use [\RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator.php)

```
$iterator = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator(getcwd(), \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$iterator = new \RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator(
  $iterator,
  function ($item) {
    return $item->getExtension() === 'php' ? true : false;
  }
);
```

Iterator now will contains only PHP files.

```
 foreach($iterator as $file) {
   echo $file;
 }
```

Comment: The example code is incorrect. The callback should return boolean; `true` to accept the tested item, `false` otherwise.  Also, by not returning `true` if `$item` has children you are breaking the ability to recurse.

Comment: `Undefined variable: skip` any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Cross-posting [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105810/view-files-in-directory-with-pagination-php/14617453#14617453) ([also in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938936/paging-listed-files-from-a-directory/14617409#14617409) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204378/paginate-list-of-files-in-php/14617446#14617446)) --

Turning `glob` into an iterator seems to prefilter more easily than writing a custom [`FilterIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php).  Also note that `FilterIterator` still steps through each item during iteration, just ignores it, whereas glob doesn't seem to.  *However*, `glob` seems to include rather than exclude, so may not fit your scenario.

**No prefilter:**

```
$dir_iterator = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
$paginated = new LimitIterator($dir_iterator, $page * $perpage, $perpage);
```

**Glob prefilter:**

```
$dir_glob = $dir . '/*.{jpg,gif,png}';

$dir_iterator = new ArrayObject(glob($dir_glob, GLOB_BRACE)); // need to get iterator
$dir_iterator = $dir_iterator->getIterator();
$paginated = new LimitIterator($dir_iterator, $page * $perpage, $perpage);
```

**Then, do your thing:**

```
foreach ($paginated as $file) { ... }
```

Note that in the case of the `DirectoryIterator` example, `$file` will be an instance of [`SplFileInfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php), whereas `glob` example is just the disk path.

---

**Example `FilterIterator` extension**

```
class ExtensionFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {
    private $filter;

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator , $filter) {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->filter = $filter;
    }

    // the meat and potatoes
    public function accept() {
        $current = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();

        ### global $counter;
        ### print_r(array($counter++, $current)); // this proves it goes through the whole thing, even with limit

    // do your comparison


        // assume path
        if( is_string($current) ) {
            $extension = end( explode('.', $current) );
        }
        // assume DirectoryIterator
        else {
            // $ext = $fileinfo->getExtension(); // http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php
            $extension = pathinfo($current->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // < PHP 5.3.6 -- http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getextension.php
        }

        return !    in_array($extension,$this->filter);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$dir_iterator = new ExtensionFilterIterator(new DirectoryIterator($dir), array('gif', 'jpg', 'png'));
$paginated = new LimitIterator($dir_iterator, $page * $perpage, $perpage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the other answers, you could do the filtering in a cleaner way by specialising [`RecursiveFilterIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivefilteriterator.php).  Eg, the [`finfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php)-based approach:

```
class MyRecursiveFilterIterator extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
    private $finfo;

    function __construct(RecursiveIterator $i)
    {
        $this->finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        parent::__construct($i);
    }

    /**
     * Filter out files with a MIME type of image/*
     */
    public function accept()
    {
        $file = $this->current();
        $filetype = $this->finfo->file($file);

        $type_parts = explode("/", $filetype, 2);
        $type = $type_parts[0];

        return ("image" !== $type);
    }

}

$scan_it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".");

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new MyRecursiveFilterIterator($scan_it)) as $file)
{
    print ("$file\n");
}
```

Similarly you could use [`RecursiveRegexIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveregexiterator.php) if you want to use the filename-based approach.

Answer (score 1):

I love examples and here is one

I was looking a way to filter extension.You can include/ exclude extensions.

```
<?php

$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
// could use CHILD_FIRST if you so wish

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    echo $file, "\n";
}

?>
```

$file will be an SplFileInfo class, so you can do powerful stuff really easily:

```
<?php


foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        echo $file->getExtension(); //By this you are king and you can access more functions of SplFileInfo
    }
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) PHP function that returns information about a file.

> The functions in this module try to guess the content type and encoding of a file by looking for certain magic byte sequences at specific positions within the file. While this is not a bullet proof approach the heuristics used do a very good job.

**Code**

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$scan_it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/example_dir");

 foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($scan_it) as $file) {
  echo finfo_file($finfo, $file) . "<br/>";
  }
finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

The **output** should be something like:

```
image/png
directory
image/png
image/svg+xml
```

**Edit**

So you can take the non-image files with something like that:

```
if(!preg_match("/image.*/",finfo_file($finfo, $file)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
// Get all files ending with ".php" in folder
$folder = __DIR__ . '/example_dir';

$iterator = new RegexIterator(
    new DirectoryIterator($folder), // You can change this to RecursiveDirectoryIterator it you want
    '/\.php$/i',
    RegexIterator::MATCH
);

/** @var SplFileInfo $field_file */
foreach ($r_iterator as $field_file) {
    echo $field_file->getPathname();
}
```