# How to list all the folders and its files in php

Tags: php, file, sorting, directory, scandir

I have a folder and it contains directories in it.Some of the directories contains files and some other contains another directory with its file.What I want is list all the files from the   folder.Suppose my folder is A and it contains folder B and C.B contains some mp3 files and in C there is another folder D and in D there are some mp3 files.How it possible to list all mp3 files from B and D.Please help.

Comment: Did you try something? Start with [`dir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php)

Comment: lookup `glob()` and `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function find_all_files($dir) 
{ 
    $root = scandir($dir); 
    foreach($root as $value) 
    { 
        if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {continue;} 
        if(is_file("$dir/$value")) {$result[]="$dir/$value";continue;} 
        foreach(find_all_files("$dir/$value") as $value) 
        { 
            $result[]=$value; 
        } 
    } 
    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: you should include the link of your code source: http://ch2.php.net/scandir

Comment: Nope. I used it in my code long ago. Forgot from where I copied.

Comment: sound good. check the link also.

Comment: nice you checked. Finally got the source :)

Answer (score 0):

while scanning directory you only want mp3 files. try directory iterator

```
$scan_it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/example_dir");

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($scan_it) as $file) {
  if (strtolower(substr($file, -4)) == ".mp3") {
    echo $file;
  }
}
```

[How to exclude file types from Directory Iterator loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141468/how-to-exclude-file-types-from-directory-iterator-loop)

Answer (score -1):

```
 function Read_Dir($dir) {
        $dh = opendir($dir);
        $files = array();
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $flag = false;
            if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
                  // check here if file is a directory then use it recursively
                $files[] = trim($file);

            }
        }
        return $files;

    }
```

> Hope it helps