# Paginate list of files in php

Tags: php, file-io, pagination

I have php code for list all ".swf" files in a folder. (The name of the files is always: 
"99-dd-mm-YY_HH-mm-ss.swf", example: "01-19-06-2011_18-40-00.swf".
When I have more than 500 files in the folder is complicated to see and to refresh the page.

I need paginate the list of files.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{    
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="some.php" method="post">
<?php
   echo "\n<br>\n";


echo "<a href='javascript:this.location.reload();' style='color: #000000; font-weight: normal'>Refresh</a></br>";
   echo "<tr>\n<td>\n<a href='javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)'>\n";
   echo "<img src='../../inc/img/back.png' alt='Back'";
   echo " border=0>\n";
   echo "<b>&nbsp;Back</b></a></td>\n";
   echo "\n</tr>\n";
   echo "\n<br>\n\n<br>\n";
$folder='.';
function order($a,$b){
global $folder;
$directory='.';
return strcmp(strtolower($a), strtolower($b));
}
$folder=opendir($folder);
while($files=readdir($folder)){

$ext = pathinfo($files, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if ($ext == 'swf')  {  //con esta línea saco el nombre index.php del listado
$file[]=$files;
usort($file, "order");
}
}
$n = 0;
foreach($file as $archiv){
   $n = $n + 1;
   $day = substr($archiv, 3,10);
   $day = str_replace("-","/", $day);
   $hour = substr($archiv, 14,8);
   $hour = str_replace("-",":", $hour);
   echo "<img alt='Ver $archiv' src='../../inc/img/video.png'> Video $n, Día: $day, hour: $hour\n ";
   echo "<input type='submit' name='xxx' value='$archiv'></td>\n";
   echo "\n</tr>\n";
   echo "<br>";
}
closedir($folder);
   echo "\n<br>\n";
   echo "<tr>\n<td>\n<a href='javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)'>\n";
   echo "<img src='../../inc/img/back.png' alt='Back'";
   echo " border=0>\n";
   echo "<b>&nbsp;Back</b></a></td>\n";
   echo "\n</tr>\n";
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to paginate a list of files and.. something doesn't work? What exactly is the problem. Does it give an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code for simple pagination

```
<?php
// Include the pagination class
include 'pagination.class.php';
// Create the pagination object
$pagination = new pagination;

// some example data
foreach (range(1, 100) as $value) {
$products[] = array(
'Product' => 'Product '.$value,
'Price' => rand(100, 1000),
);
}

// If we have an array with items
if (count($products)) {
// Parse through the pagination class
$productPages = $pagination->generate($products, 20);
// If we have items
if (count($productPages) != 0) {
// Create the page numbers
echo $pageNumbers = '<div>'.$pagination->links().'</div>';
// Loop through all the items in the array
foreach ($productPages as $productID => $productArray) {
// Show the information about the item
echo '<p><b>'.$productArray['Product'].'</b> 243'.$productArray['Price'].'</p>';
}
// print out the page numbers beneath the results
echo $pageNumbers;
}
}
?>
```

Here there is pagination class and the example for download:
http://lotsofcode.com/php/php-array-pagination.htm

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

When required to go through lots of folders and files, try the Iterator object. A nice example:

```
function get_files($dir)
{
  $dir  = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
  $list = iterator_to_array($dir, false);
  return array_slice($list, 2);
}
```

This will get all the file names (if you have php 5.3 or higher) very fast and will do the if dir_exists / file_exists for you! The array_slice so it removes the . and .. directory.

Comment: Very nice! Did not know about that function :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Like @Tessmore said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204444/1037948), Spl Iterators are *teh awesomesauce*.  According to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), you only need PHP > 5.1 for the basic iterators.

[Cross-posting an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938936/paging-listed-files-from-a-directory/14617409#14617409) --

[`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) and [`LimitIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php) are my new best friends, although `glob` seems to prefilter more easily.  You could also write a custom [`FilterIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php).  Needs PHP > 5.1, I think.

**No prefilter:**

```
$dir_iterator = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
$paginated = new LimitIterator($dir_iterator, $page * $perpage, $perpage);
```

**Glob prefilter:**

```
$dir_glob = $dir . '/*.{jpg,gif,png}';

$dir_iterator = new ArrayObject(glob($dir_glob, GLOB_BRACE));
$dir_iterator = $dir_iterator->getIterator();
$paginated = new LimitIterator($dir_iterator, $page * $perpage, $perpage);
```

**Then, do your thing:**

```
foreach ($paginated as $file) { ... }
```

Note that in the case of the `DirectoryIterator` example, `$file` will be an instance of [`SplFileInfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php), whereas `glob` example is just the disk path.